# How to join two firebase tables

Tags: angularjs, join, binding, firebase

We have a firebase database with two tables, the json objects look like the following

```
Messages : {
  M1 : {
      Id: 1,
      Message: "TEST",
      UserId: 2
   }
}
Users : {
  U1 : {
     Id: 1,
     UserName: "TEST",
     Password: 2
   }
}
```

I want to be able to display all the messages with the user name next to each one.

How can I join the tables and still keep the [Three-way Bindings](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html#section-three-way-bindings),
so that we can show the UserName instead of the Id that we currently show.

we currently use `$firebaseArray` like this:

```
var messangerCtrl = this; 
var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/<my-app>/Messages");

messangerCtrl.viewModel={
    messages :  $firebaseArray(ref),
    message: ""
};
```

and the markup looks like this

```
<div ng-controller="MessangerController as messangerCtrl">
 <div class="messanger-main">    
  <div ng-repeat="mes in messangerCtrl.viewModel.messages | orderBy:'id'"> 
    {{mes.userId}}:  {{mes.message}}
  </div>
 </div>
 .
 .
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: You could store the user name inside the message.

Comment: Yes.. But I'd like to know how to do join or left join..